# ASP.NET 2.0 Custom Client Side Validation not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, c#-2.0, custom-validators

I have two text boxes, one for a scheduled date, and the other for a scheduled time. I want to pass validation if both text boxes are blank, or both have content. I want to fail validation if only one has content. All is working fine server side, and the following client-side code is working correctly in Chrome.

```
    function CheckScheduledDateTime(sender, args) {
        if (ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledTime.value!="" || ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledDate.value!="" )
        {
            if (ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledTime.value!="" && ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledDate.value=="")
            {
                args.IsValid=false;
                alert("Scheduled date is required");
            }
            else if (ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledTime.value=="" && ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledDate.value1!="")
            {
                args.IsValid=false;
                alert("Scheduled time is required");
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid=true;
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }         
    }
```

In Internet Explorer, it does not work, and I am getting the following error:

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledTime' is undefined"

The strange thing is, with it broken in Visual Studio, if I then try and step into into once more, it breaks again, but then if I try and step into it a third time it runs, and the validation works properly.

Is anybody able to shed some light on this?

Comment: are you using document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledTime')?

Comment: This code was actually taken from the browser rendered code, I'm using `<%=txtScheduledTime.ClientID%>.value` in all places where you see `ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledTime.value`, likewise for the date field. I'm not using document.getElementById.

Comment: Changing to  `if (document.getElementById('<%=txtScheduledTime.ClientID%>').value!="" || document.getElementById('<%=txtScheduledDate.ClientID%>').value!="" )` has worked a treat, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to add that in as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this

ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledTime are not javascript variables until you initialize them using

```
var ctl00_MainContent_txtScheduledTime = document.getElementById('<%=txtScheduledTime.ClientID%>');
```

or you can use it like

```
(document.getElementById('<%=txtScheduledTime.ClientID%>').value!="" || document.getElementById('<%=txtScheduledDate.ClientID%>').value!="" )
```

Regards.